# Creating simple id for session

Tags: mongodb, session

I got a simple WS that acts like a session server, nothing complex at all.
When I create a session, I got an _id from Mongo that I cannot give back to user cause of the sequence used by mongo.

Example of ids sequence when chaining the creation:

```
536004fe2e1d59c95e9155a8
536004fe2e1d59c95e9155a9
536004fe2e1d59c95e9155aa
536004fe2e1d59c95e9155ab
```

As u can see, can ask a session and try to figure out next ones...

My question is: what sort of tricks do you use to create random but (nearly) unique id?

- sha1/md5/... of the mongo _id, stored on the db. Implication is save + update
- Using one-way encryption on the fly on the _id
- Do not use a session db... Hey ! I have no choice !!
- ... ?

Answer (score 1):

I use Redis for the session data for our site because it offers high read/write performance and key lookup is the only thing needed for session data. Why are you using MongoDB for your session store?

In any case, you can [assign the _id before saving it](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#the-id-field) to MongoDB, and it will use that instead of auto-generating one. If you set the _id to a UUID (what I use for my key) or some other random value, you can use that without any performance degradation.

Comment: Cause sometimes, boss takes decisions :(  Thanks for the tips to assign before saving.

Answer (score -1):

I tend to use MD5 of my current timestamp, it's almost "unique".

You could generate it and post it as any other field on a mongo document, no need to use _id.

Note that i've never used mongo, i use CouchBase and views.

Comment: I believe he is looking for two important features that a session id should have: randomness and uniqueness. MD5 of current timestamp may produce unique value but it is not random.